# Is there way to convert date into timestamp with smarty

Tags: smarty

I need to calculate a date based on a membership but this has to done with timestamp to have a common numeric value.
We've read almost the whole smarty.net documentation and couldn't find our solution.

This would have been our best trick:

`{capture assign="end_date"}{latestcurrentmembership.end_date}{/capture}{$fin = $end_date|strtotime}`

but either `capture assign` and `strtotime` seem to be working within CiviCRM.
Any idea?

EDIT 1: `capture assign` works well, it's `strtotime` that seems to not work within CiviCRM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer came later on:

> {latestcurrentmembership.end_date-31536000|date_format:'%Y%m%d'}

I only add to subtract one year in seconds

Answer (score 2):

```
{capture assign="end_date"}{latestcurrentmembership.end_date}{/capture}

// convert it to strtotime
{assign var='end_date' value=$end_date|strtotime}

or 

{assign var='end_date' value=$end_date|date_format:"%s"}

// display in date format 
{$end_date|date_format:'%Y%m%d'}
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: this doesn't work, the pdf is triggered with a CiviRule based on a Tag and we can't even tick the check box without getting an error.  Smarty is on '1' in settings. Do I need anything else in the configuration? We've tried other operations and they were effective.
what you wrote is one of the variations we tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: actually in your code it's the`strtotime` that pertubates the sending of the e-mail :-( without it the e-mail is sent

Comment: Instead of the `strtotime`, this works for me (on unix, but not windows): `{$end_date|date_format:"%s"}`

Comment: Thanks, @Demerit I have updated my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: To make things more interesting - `date_format` is deprecated in Civi with Smarty 3+.  So you're back to using `strtotime`.